# Perl script for normalizing negative numbers

Tags: perl

I have several large csv files in which I would like to replace all numbers less than 100, including negative numbers with 500 or another positive number.

I'm not a programmer but I found a nice perl one liner to replace the white space with comma `'s/[^\S\n]+/,/g'`. I was wondering if there's any easy way to do this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me, assuming there are 2 files in the directory:

test1.txt:

```
201,400,-1
-2.5,677,90.66,30.32
222,18
```

test2.txt

```
-1,-1,-1,99,101
3,3,222,190,-999
22,100,100,3
```

using the one liner:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/(-?\d+\.?\d*)/$1<100?500:$1/ge' *
```

`-p` will apply the search-replace process to each line in each file, `-i.bak` means do the replacement in the original files and backup those files with new files having `.bak` extension. `s///ge` part will find all the numbers (including negative numbers) and then compare each number with 100, if less than 100 then replace it with 500. `g` means find all match numbers. `e` means the replacement part will be treated as Perl code. `*` means process all the files in the directory

After executed this one liner, I got 4 files in the directory as:

```
test1.txt.bak test1.txt test2.txt.bak test2.txt
```

and the content for test1.txt and test2.txt are:

test1.txt

```
201,400,500
500,677,500,500
222,500
```

test2.txt

```
500,500,500,500,101
500,500,222,190,500
500,100,100,500
```

Comment: this worked great. Is it possible to do or is is larger than a certain number or do I just have to run it twice?

Comment: do you mean whether it work on more files? it will process all the files in the target directory, I just put 2 files there to make an example.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows formatting for a perl 1-liner

```
perl -F/,/ -lane "print join(q{,},map{/^[-\d.]+$/ && $_ < 100 ? 100: $_} @F),qq{\n};" input.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: `/^[-\d.]/` does same thing, and `<` can be dropped in `< input.csv` Also `qq{\n}` will make double newlines (`-l` switch)

Comment: whatcha mean `/^[-\d.]/` does the same thing?  And I'll drop the input arrow.

Comment: Since you're not matching till end `$` of number, matching one, or more digits does not make difference.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you did differently now. Aye. So i added the `$` boundary.  It's not a perfect IsNum test, but good enough to avoid most potential errors.